# Swift Crash in Gesture Update

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uipangesturerecognizer, wkwebview

I am using a constraint to set a boundary between two views.  A pan gesture is used to track the vertical movement of the users finger in dragging the boundary.

When the dragging goes on too long the app crashes with almost no explanation.  Below is the output from a crash (other crashes have produced much shorter output), which I don't understand.  The code that I think is relevant is below it.

Your help in understanding and correcting this is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x180d95bc0 <+0>:   cmp    x0, #0
    0x180d95bc4 <+4>:   b.le   0x180d95c2c               ; <+108>
->  0x180d95bc8 <+8>:   ldr    x13, [x0]
    0x180d95bcc <+12>:  and    x9, x13, #0x1fffffff8
    0x180d95bd0 <+16>:  ldp    x10, x11, [x9, #16]
    0x180d95bd4 <+20>:  and    w12, w1, w11
    0x180d95bd8 <+24>:  add    x12, x10, x12, lsl #4
    0x180d95bdc <+28>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
    0x180d95be0 <+32>:  cmp    x16, x1
    0x180d95be4 <+36>:  b.ne   0x180d95bec               ; <+44>
    0x180d95be8 <+40>:  br     x17
    0x180d95bec <+44>:  cbz    x16, 0x180d95d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
    0x180d95bf0 <+48>:  cmp    x12, x10
    0x180d95bf4 <+52>:  b.eq   0x180d95c00               ; <+64>
    0x180d95bf8 <+56>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
    0x180d95bfc <+60>:  b      0x180d95be0               ; <+32>
    0x180d95c00 <+64>:  add    x12, x12, w11, uxtw #4
    0x180d95c04 <+68>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
    0x180d95c08 <+72>:  cmp    x16, x1
    0x180d95c0c <+76>:  b.ne   0x180d95c14               ; <+84>
    0x180d95c10 <+80>:  br     x17
    0x180d95c14 <+84>:  cbz    x16, 0x180d95d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
    0x180d95c18 <+88>:  cmp    x12, x10
    0x180d95c1c <+92>:  b.eq   0x180d95c28               ; <+104>
    0x180d95c20 <+96>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
    0x180d95c24 <+100>: b      0x180d95c08               ; <+72>
    0x180d95c28 <+104>: b      0x180d95d80               ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
    0x180d95c2c <+108>: b.eq   0x180d95c44               ; <+132>
    0x180d95c30 <+112>: adrp   x10, 123003
    0x180d95c34 <+116>: add    x10, x10, #816
    0x180d95c38 <+120>: lsr    x11, x0, #60
    0x180d95c3c <+124>: ldr    x9, [x10, x11, lsl #3]
    0x180d95c40 <+128>: b      0x180d95bd0               ; <+16>
    0x180d95c44 <+132>: movz   x1, #0
    0x180d95c48 <+136>: movi   d0, #0000000000000000
    0x180d95c4c <+140>: movi   d1, #0000000000000000
    0x180d95c50 <+144>: movi   d2, #0000000000000000
    0x180d95c54 <+148>: movi   d3, #0000000000000000
    0x180d95c58 <+152>: ret    
    0x180d95c5c <+156>: nop
```

Below is the code that is called by the pan gesture recognizer:

```
@IBAction func pan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .Ended:
        captureViewSplit()
        saveSermonSettingsBackground()
        break

    case .Changed:
        let translation = gesture.translationInView(splitView)
        let change = -translation.y
        if change != 0 {
            gesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: splitView)
            setSermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint(change)
            self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            self.view.layoutSubviews()
        }
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the constraint update:

```
private func setSermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint(change:CGFloat)
{
    let newConstraintConstant = self.sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint.constant + change

    let (minConstraintConstant,maxConstraintConstant) = sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraintMinMax(self.view.bounds.height)

    if (newConstraintConstant >= minConstraintConstant) && (newConstraintConstant <= maxConstraintConstant) {
        self.sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint.constant = newConstraintConstant
    } else {
        if newConstraintConstant < minConstraintConstant { self.sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint.constant = minConstraintConstant }
        if newConstraintConstant > maxConstraintConstant { self.sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint.constant = maxConstraintConstant }
    }
    splitView.min = minConstraintConstant
    splitView.max = maxConstraintConstant
    splitView.height = self.sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraint.constant
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}

private func sermonNotesAndSlidesConstraintMinMax(height:CGFloat) -> (min:CGFloat,max:CGFloat)
{
    let minConstraintConstant:CGFloat = tableView.rowHeight*1 + slider.bounds.height + 16 //margin on top and bottom of slider

    let maxConstraintConstant:CGFloat = height - logo.bounds.height - slider.bounds.height - navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.height

    return (minConstraintConstant,maxConstraintConstant)
}
```

Below is the code for the custom class that draws the graphic that delineates the split between the two views.

```
@IBDesignable
class SplitView: UIView {
    var splitViewController:UISplitViewController?

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    var height:CGFloat = 200 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var min:CGFloat = 50 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var max:CGFloat = 500 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    private var splitCenter: CGPoint? {
        var splitPoint:CGPoint?

        splitPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.width / 2, self.bounds.height - height)

        return splitPoint
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        if let startingPoint = splitCenter {
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextSaveGState(context)

            let indicatorPath = UIBezierPath()

            let height:CGFloat = bounds.width/4

            let left = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x - bounds.width/2, y: startingPoint.y)
            indicatorPath.moveToPoint(left)

            let right = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x + bounds.width/2, y: startingPoint.y)
            indicatorPath.addLineToPoint(right)

//            print("startingPoint.y: \(round(startingPoint.y)) min: \(round(min)) max: \(round(max))")

            if (round(startingPoint.y) > (bounds.height - round(max))) {
                let bottom = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x, y: startingPoint.y - height)
                indicatorPath.moveToPoint(bottom)
                indicatorPath.addLineToPoint(left)
                indicatorPath.moveToPoint(bottom)
                indicatorPath.addLineToPoint(right)
            }

            if (round(startingPoint.y) < (bounds.height - round(min))) {
                let top = CGPoint(x: startingPoint.x, y: startingPoint.y + height)
                indicatorPath.moveToPoint(top)
                indicatorPath.addLineToPoint(left)
                indicatorPath.moveToPoint(top)
                indicatorPath.addLineToPoint(right)
            }

            indicatorPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
            color.set()
            indicatorPath.stroke()

            let boundsPath = UIBezierPath()

            boundsPath.moveToPoint(bounds.origin)
            boundsPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.width, y: bounds.origin.y))

            if (splitViewController == nil) {
                boundsPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.width,    y: splitCenter!.y))
                boundsPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x,                   y: splitCenter!.y))
            } else {
                boundsPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + bounds.width,    y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.height))
                boundsPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x,                   y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.height))
            }

            boundsPath.addLineToPoint(bounds.origin)

            boundsPath.lineWidth = lineWidth / 2
            color.set()
            boundsPath.stroke()

            CGContextRestoreGState(context)
        } else {
            print("No starting point!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an example of the more common, shorter crash output I often get when I drag for a long time.

CoreGraphics `CGPDFPageGetProperty:
    0x182a182a8 <+0>:  cbz    x0, 0x182a182b4           ; <+12>
->  0x182a182ac <+4>:  ldr    x0, [x0, #40]
    0x182a182b0 <+8>:  b      0x1829f9f08               ; pdf_page_get_property
    0x182a182b4 <+12>: movz   x0, #0
    0x182a182b8 <+16>: ret`

I should have added to the original post that one view is a UITableView and the other includes a WKWebView that has a PDF loaded via a URL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was setting the WKWebView's scrollView delegate, which from experience, I found had to be set to nil on viewWillDisappear() or the app would crash.  By setting the delegate to nil on .Began in the pan gesture recognizer and back to self on .Ended the problem went away.